# How to update bundler version in dokku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, dokku

I use dokku 0.12.5

How to update bundler version `gem bundle install` doesn't work

**Update:**

```
root@TM:~# dokku run app gem update bundler
Updating installed gems
Updating bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.16.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.1
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.1
Installing darkfish documentation for bundler-1.16.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 7 seconds
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
Gems updated: bundler
root@TM:~# dokku run app bundler -v
Bundler version 1.15.2
```

Comment: gem install bundler